# Is changing the Dropbox share link officially supported? (In order to get around CORS)

Tags: cors, dropbox

Currently I can access the contents of a file shared publicly on Dropbox by changing the url to match dl.droboxusercontent.com/s/folder/file. This is being used in client side web app which is served to a limited audience. There is almost no chance of generating too much traffic. I cannot find anywhere on the Dropbox help/developer page where this is mentioned. Is this method officially supported? I started to look into the API, but then found this method works just fine as is.

This is for a file not stored in the 'Public' folder.

Per the new comments - I am using this method along with omnivore in leaflet, and the official Dropbox method for accessing the raw file (?raw=1) throws a CORS error:

```
omnivore.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/folder/file.csv?raw=1").addTo(map);
```

While the rewritten url does not:

```
omnivore.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/folder/file.csv").addTo(map);
```

Comment: I think you're looking for https://www.dropbox.com/help/201.

Comment: I think this question shouldn't have the "leaflet" tag.

Answer (score 1):

The official methods for getting to file content via a Dropbox shared link is documented here:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/201

Specifically, that recommends using the documented URL parameters and following redirects.

The method of directly changing the host to dl.dropboxusercontent.com isn't documented, so it's not considered officially supported.

That said, if you need to use that method for whatever reason, e.g., CORS, you can do so at your own risk. (And it may be wise to code around it extra defensively, in case it breaks without warning.)

Comment: If found another discussion in the official Dropbox forums that might be helpful: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/202364979-CORS-issue-when-trying-to-download-shared-file